# Insert newline <br> at the end of textarea line

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form (an within the form inter alia a textarea) which is send by an ajax post request to a php file. In the php file I send a html mail with the content of the form. The textarea has a fixed size (cols, rows and maxlength).

This is the textarea:

```
<textarea class="form-control font-consolas" id="hellotext"
              wrap="hard" cols="36" rows="10" style="width: auto" maxlength="360"
              data-limit-rows="true"
              name="hellotext" required></textarea>
```

I successfully convert the new line:

```
var hellotext = encodeURIComponent($("#hellotext").val());
hellotext = hellotext.replace(/%0A/g,"<br>");
```

This is an example of a converted text:

```
 Hello, this is a short test. Now a NewLine is coming in the word previous NewLine.

 Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaats a short teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest (new line in teeeeeeest).

 NeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeLine
```

But the text should make each line a NewLine at character 36. Of course, a whole word must not be truncated, but a word longer than 36 characters should be. As the user sees it in the input:
[image]

Comment: When text wraps in the `textarea` a there are no newline characters added. Similar to when text wraps in a `div` the original string remains the same with no newline characters. I'd advise against adding characters, or line breaks, that were not added by the user. Let the `div` on the receiving page handle text wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use editable div? It automatically breaks the lines you want. Given that you provide the right styling to the receiving end. e.g. white-space: pre-line

Click here to know how to add the div manually to the form: [Getting value from contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810182/getting-value-from-contenteditable-div)

```js
let editablediv = document.querySelector('div')

function output(str){
  document.querySelector('pre').textContent=str
}

editablediv.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){
  output(event.target.innerText)
} )

let msg = 'Nehemiah 8:10 \n\n Do not grieve, for the joy of the Lord is your strength. Isaiah 41:10 So do not fear, for I am with you; do not be dismayed, for I am your God. I will strengthen you and help you; I will uphold you with my righteous right hand.'

editablediv.textContent=msg
output(msg)
```

```css
pre{
white-space:pre-line;
width:50%;
}
#ed{
border:1px solid #000;
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<label for=ed><h3>Editable Div</h3>
Click on the box below to edit it;</label>
<div id=ed contenteditable=true></div>

<h3>Output</h3>
<pre></pre>
```